# Convert List of Enums to a SelectList and maintain display?

Tags: c#, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

We have a view that is driven by a List of options.  Depending on the initial conditions, a DropDownList is created with choices for the user's next step.  This list is populated with choices from a larger list of options encased within a custom Enumeration.

So we have an Enum like so:

```
public enum ChangeMode
{
    [Display(Name ="Please Select")] InitialState,
    [Display(Name = "Change A Thing")] ChangeThing,
    //...
    [Display(Name = "Do a Dance")] DoADance,
    FinishedSuccess,
    FinishedFailure
}
```

And in the controller for the view, we build a List that contains all the valid options for the user, which is NEVER the full list.

```
if( /*Irrelevant determining characteristic*/ )
{//Valid choices for this option
    model.ValidModes = new List<ChangeMode> { ChangeMode.InitialState, ChangeMode.ChangeThing};
}
```

We then create a DropDownList in the view, based on the model's list of ChangeModes

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.AlterMethod, new SelectList(Model.ValidModes))
```

All of this is working just fine, except that the generated DDL does not include the user-friendly Name that each mode is assigned, instead showing the Enum's developer-readable value ('InitialState', for example).  How do I change this to have the View correctly render the dropdownlist such that it uses the Display(Name) as the Text for the DDL?

Comment: use reflection to get the enum attribute.

Comment: @iSR5 - Honestly, I have never really used reflection.  I know (at a high level) what it is and what power it has, but have no idea how to begin doing so.  Can you drop an answer with more details?

Comment: Can you show the code that builds the Model?

Comment: @Dennis1679: Sure, added.  It's not anything unusual or extraordinary though.

Comment: Thank you. It is actually a bit unusual as it shows that what you're basically trying to do here is instantiate an enum class. I'll write an answer that will solve what you're trying to do - and provide you with a nice dropdown list. Hopefully. Give me second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the values from your Enum attributes. To do this, you need a helper method that will return the attribute.

here is a helper method to access Enum attributes:

```
public T GetAttribute<T>(Enum _enum) where T : Attribute
{
    return 
        (T)_enum.GetType()
                .GetField(Enum.GetName(_enum.GetType(), _enum))
                .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T));
}
```

Usage :

```
var name = GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(ChangeMode.InitialState).Name;
```

Comment: This is the method I ended up choosing.  I edited my controller and model to create a list of SelectItems instead of a list of enums, and built the SelectItems as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

> ASP.NET Core ships with a helper for generating a SelectListItem for
>   **any** enum.

This means that if you have an enum of the `TEnum` type, you can generate the available options in your 
View using `asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<TEnum>()"`.

Change:

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.AlterMethod, new SelectList(Model.ValidModes))
```

To:

```cs
<select asp-for="AlterMethod" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Enums.ChangeMode>()"></select>
```

Or if you only want the Values from `ValidModes`:

```cs
<select asp-for="AlterMethod" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(Model.ValidModes))"></select>
```

Comment: Won't this populate the SelectList with all of the possible values of the Enum?  Because that's pretty much the opposite of what I'm trying to do.  I **explicitly** only want the Valid Modes that the user can select to be in the list.

Comment: What type is ValidModes?

Comment: ValidModes is a List<ChangeMode> that is populated by the controller.

Comment: But wouldn't List<ChangeMode> just be a list of the ChangeMode enum and still hold all of the possible enum values?

Comment: No, because I build and populate it with just specific values in the Controller.

Comment: Your edit does not help, sadly.  It could be my workplace is using an older version, but a select item written as you recomment (using the asp-for and asp-items decorators) are simply rendering as typed.

Comment: I am both very curious to see how you are building that enum, as confused as to why a List<TEnum> is what you need. This feels like a typical XY problem and I think we're trying to fix something that should not be solved but designed differently.